# What is the maximum number of 3 pointers made by Michael Jordan in a single game?

Tags: trivia, statistics, nba, records

What is the maximum number of 3 pointers made by Michael Jordan in a single game?
Although it sounds simple, I couldn't find this stat in the internet.

Answer (score 7):

Going through his [yearly game logs on Basketball Reference](http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jordami01/gamelog/1990/), the answer is 7. This took place on [January 18, 1990](http://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/199001180CHI.html).